# POST multipart-data handling boundary

Tags: html, ios, post

I'm trying to create a http server that handles multipart POST for uploading files for the iPhone. However, when I get the data from the socket coming in, it is just NSData. When I pipe that through and NSOutputStream to a file, the file is corrupt because it has the boundary information and other junk inside of this like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQAQ0rA7ohYLNLt3b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dummyname"; filename="bright_squares-2.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryZDu6P3zNanvqB4Bp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dummyname"; filename="bright_squares.png"
Content-Type: image/png

{content}
```

I tried converting the NSData coming in from the network to an NSString and to strip the boundary information from it but that is failing and the NSData won't convert to an NSString so I can strip the junk. It just ends up being nil.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [iPhone HTTP server](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/downloads/detail?name=iPhoneHTTPServer3.zip&can=1&q=).  It will allow you to upload/download files to iOS devices.  You may be able to pickup something to help with your coding if you chose to DIY.

Comment: That's what I'm using as a base :). It doesn't support multipart POST uploads and I'm attempting to modify it to do so.